# Finding height and speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics

A small puck of mass **m** glides along a smooth horizontal table at a speed **v0** to a shiftable slide of mass **3m** that is at rest, the puck up the slide with no friction and then glides down the slope in the opposite direction.

1- what is the maximum height of the puck on the slope?

2- At what speed will the puck leave the slope?

Is this a PE KE question? Also, why speed and not velocity? What could be the difference here?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to visualise it.

1) When the puck hits the slide, the puck will rise up the slide and the slide will recoil.

2) As the puck rises it will lose KE to PE and also share KE with the recoiling slide.

3) At the top of its rise the puck will be stationary with respect to the slide. At that point the puck and slide will be a combined mass of 4m. Since momentum is conserved, the combined mass will have a velocity of V0/4. The KE of the combined mass will be a quarter of the initial KE of the puck (because the mass will have increased by 4, but the V-squared term will be reduced by 16). Given that, the remaining energy will be transformed into PE of the puck, so you can calculate it straightforwardl

4) When the puck leaves the slide, because there has been no frictional losses, the recoil of the slide will be like an elastic collision, so you can calculate the recoil velocity using the usual formulas for an elastic collision.

5) The above is a simplification, because it ignores the recoil of the earth downwards.

6) The question is written in terms of speed because the direction of motion is irrelevant.

Comment: then as i understand, the height would be PE(3/4) initial KE divided by g.m of the puck?

Comment: That sounds right.